# Get the right var config when selecting a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this var configs

```
var room_type = $("#room-type").val();

var room_price_1 = '1500';
var room_price_2 = '0';
var room_price_3 = '0';

var total = room_price_'+room_type+'';

alert(total);
```

i want to get the room price of vars that are already set. if room type is 1 i want to get price of room_price_1 and so on. like showing me the `room_price_[selected room value]`

Comment: Could you provide your HTML or preferably a fiddle

Comment: @user3008011 (imho)no need it is clear enough

Comment: @RoyiNamir You are correct, I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than hacking your variable calls, I recommend using an Array:

```
var room_type = $("#room-type").val();

var room_prices = ['1500','0','0'];

var total = room_prices[(room_type-1)];

alert(total);
```

Comment: Thanks, this wokred too!

Comment: I like this way you did it. thank you, i looked for something like this but didn't know how to do it. thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var total = window['room_price_'+room_type];
```

Will be work correctly only if total defined in global scope.

Comment: I did this `var total = window['room_price_'+room_type]; alert(total);` but i get undefined

Comment: If showing me the selected value :P is 1 or 2 or 3. but i did the trick. thank you for your time. have a good day sir!

Comment: I was wondering if I downvote it or not, I decided not to but ask you to edit your answer and mention that it is possible just when you create the variables in the window context. like when you create variables in the console.

Comment: Added some description text.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
var total = eval('room_price_'+room_type);
```

if you use:

```
window['room_price_'+room_type]
```

you won't be able to change your context and you have to create your variables in the window context.
the other way is to create a kind of maps with room types as keys and prices as values, instead of using different variables.

Comment: @Mando Madalin: there is a green sign under the vote icons, if you want to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to set up an object to hold this information, IMO:

```
var room_type = $("#room-type").val(); // 1

var roomPrice = {
  1: 1500,
  2: 0,
  3: 0
};

var total = roomPrice[room_type]; // 1500
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var total = room_price_'+room_type+'';
```

with

```
var total = window["room_price_" + room_type];
```